# Запись видео по слоям в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Мне необходимо записывать видео прямо в игре, исключая слой UI, т.е игрок должен видеть UI, а на видео он должен отсутствовать. Посоветуйте ассет для записи видео, который будет работать на Android / IOS

Comment: Ну создайте ещё одну камеру, на которой не будет UI и пишите с неё